# Matching a URL with up to a certain number of forward slashes

Tags: regex

Is there a way to match all of the below with one regular expression? If not, what would be a good/clean way to do so?

```
/resources/$
/resources/type$
/resources/type/$
/resources/category$
/resources/category/$
/resources/anything here that includes up to 1 slash and ends with that slash
```

The following should not be matched, because of the presence of `something`:

```
/resources/type/something
/resources/category/something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
^\/resources(\/[a-z]*\/?)?$
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tweaked to also match capitals, numbers and dashes. `^\/resources(\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\/?)?$`

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
^\/([^\/]*\/?){,2}$
```

EDITED for errors :p

Comment: This falsely matches '/resources/test/something'

Comment: Thanks, but this also matches URLs that start with something other than `/resources/`, and I'm struggling to adapt it.

Comment: True. In my defense, there was nothing in your question that says that URLs other than /resources/ shouldn't be matched (although you could see it implied). I'd've put a non-/resources/ URL under "shouldn't be matched" section for a clearer question.